# javascript concesionaria

Tags: javascript, lógica

estoy trabado con este ejercicio de JS. me pide una function que retorne una lista de autos no vendidos, luego pasarle una funcion que le cambia la propiedad vendido a true y luego realizar un filter para filtrar los false. les paso el enunciado del ej y hasta donde llegue del code.

gracias!!

exerciseProgressIcon
Funcionalidad extra
La primera es poder contar, como concesionaria, con la habilidad de poder tener la lista de autos para la venta. A lo cual, María, cree que es una tarea sencilla que Juan y vos pueden encarar solos, usando la función autosParaLaVenta, aunque por las dudas ella les recuerda que no deberían de aparecer los autos que ya fueron vendidos.

Para comenzar, tenés que agregar el código que escribiste en el ejercicio anterior. Tené en cuenta que estamos optimizando nuestro código, por lo cual, deberíamos utilizar el método filter.

```
let autos = [{
marca: "Ford",
modelo: "Fiesta",
precio: 150000,
km: 200,
color: "Azul",
cuotas: 12,
anio: 2019,
patente: "APL 123",
vendido: false},
{ 
marca: "Toyota",
modelo: "Corolla",
precio: 100000,
km: 0,
color: "Blanco",
cuotas: 14,
anio: 2019,
patente: "jjk 116",
vendido: false

}] ;




let concesionaria = {
autos: autos,

autos: autos,

buscarAuto: function (patente){
  for ( let i = 0; i < autos.length; i++){
     if ( autos[i].patente === patente){
        return autos[i];
     }else {
        return null;
      }
   }
 },

 venderAuto: function(patente){
 let autoVenta = this.buscarAuto(patente);
 autoVenta.vendido = true;
 },

 autosParaLaVenta: function(patente){
  let autoEnVenta = autos.forEach(auto => {
   return autoEnVenta;});
   autoEnVenta = this.venderAuto(patente);
   autoEnVenta.filter(function(auto){
    return auto.vendido === false
  });

    }
    }
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask donde tienes el problema? no vamos a resolver todo el ejercicio por ti

Comment: el problema es que no lo encuentro.. me tira estos errores:   Al llamar a la función autosParaLaVenta debe devolver los dos autos que originalmente no están para la venta
Al vender al auto con patente 'APL123' y luego llamar a la función autosParaLaVenta debe devolver 1 auto y no incluir al mismo

Comment: 1. Tu título no ayuda a comprender cuál es el problema. 2. ¿cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el obtenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: te recomiendo hacer lo que comenta el otro usuario, por otra parte identa tu codigo, entre mas facil sea de leer, mas y mejores repuestas obtendras

Comment: y agrega los errores a al contenido de tu post.

Answer (score 0):

```
let autos = [{
    marca: "Ford",
    modelo: "Fiesta",
    color: "Azul",
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "APL123",
    vendido: false
},{
    marca: "Toyota",
    modelo: "Corolla",
    color: "Blanco",
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "JJK116",
    vendido: false
}];

let concesionaria = {
   autos: autos,
   buscarAuto: function(patente){
      for(let i = 0;i<autos.length;i++){
         if(autos[i].patente == patente) {
            return autos[i];
         }
      }
      return null;
},
venderAuto: function(patente){
   if(this.buscarAuto(patente) != null){
      let index = autos.indexOf(this.buscarAuto(patente));
      autos[index].vendido = true;
      }
},
autosParaLaVenta: function(){
return autos = this.autos.filter(function (elemento){
      return !elemento.vendido
   })
},
};
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).